# After clicking a link, open new URL and automatically *click* on tab link inside that page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, wordpress

Is it possible to implement this behavior:

I have a HTML link on one page, and after a user clicks on it, it goes to another page which has several tabs on it. Upon clicking on one of those tabs, it triggers an AJAX post call which populates and displays content for that tab.

I would like that when a user clicks a link on the previous page, it takes him to another page and automatically *clicks* a specific tab so it triggers an ajax call which displays the content for that tab.

This site is a Wordpress site, if that information helps at all.

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly, you would need an onload function on the other page... However, I really recommend against this method. Please provide what you currently have since there may be better solutions.

Comment: Consider using an anchor reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the 'from' page you can have links such as

```
 <a href="targetpage.html#customHash">Click Me</a>
```

You can set an onpage load function to load and use a trigger like this

```
 if(window.location.hash === "#customHash"){
    //my custom tab loader
 }
```

Comment: Hey, that seems to be a very simple and straightforward solution, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery Cookie plugin to achieve this. http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/

You just set the cookie on the first page, when the user clicks on the link

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value');
```

And on the next page use the jQuery on load function to check for the cookie.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out the plugin.